# REST calls to google compute engine API

Tags: java, web-services, rest, google-app-engine

I need to create vm's in google compute engine. Through google OAuth playground i can create VM, using REST service calls. Same thing i want to do using JAVA as a normal program. For this i have endpoint and request payload. I am not able to understand how we can do OAuth using java. If i pass my gmail credentials in headers Authorization, it is giving like HTTP **HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API**. Kindly suggest me how i can call those REST endpoint. Please send me step by steps or any sites.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the [google-api-client library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)
- Use a [service
  account to authenticate](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Never use your username/password in API calls or code !

Comment: Thank you koma. Initially i had tried to use the client id, client secret values. But that time its asking manually clicking of Allow. Now using service account my java program able to communicate the compute engine server. Once again thank you so much.

Comment: if that works, accept the answer pls !